# Weird binary signs when using pipe

Tags: shell, gdb, gdbserver

I am using this script to compile my program and to debug it on my embedded board:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Recompile:
make clean
make

# Erase memmory and upload the program:
{ echo 'connect';
  echo '';
  echo '';
  echo '';
  echo '';
  echo 'erase';
  echo 'loadbin program.bin , 0x0';
  echo 'r';
  echo 'q'; } | JLinkExe

# Kill any JLinkExeGDBServer:
killall JLinkGDBServer

# Set up the GDB server and connect with GDB:
JLinkGDBServer -device LPC4088 & sleep 2s && \
{ echo 'dashboard -layout source';
  echo 'dashboard source -style context 14';
  echo 'file program.elf';
  echo 'target remote :2331';
  echo 'monitor reset';
  cat; } | arm-none-eabi-gdb
```

After I run this script all of the commands are executed just fine, but there are some kind of binary signs in GDB *(screenshot)* and it looks like autocomplete in GDB isn't working at all. Furthermore, some of the GDB commands are totaly broken. If I use only `arm-none-eabi-gdb` without supplying it the commands through a pipe `|` GDB again works fine.

But I need to pass those commands...

I am using `~/.gdbinit` from [GDB Dashboard](https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard) but even if I remove it problem persists.

[image]

Comment: Which character is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke gdb this way, it's not directly connected to your terminal. You probably should instead look into starting gdb using a commandfile instead - if you put those commands into a file called, say, "myscript" and then invoke gdb with --command=myscript

that should get the setup you want done in the right way.

Comment: Your answer works but I instead used multiple `--eval-command` arguments ike this: `arm-none-eabi-gdb --eval-command='dashboard -layout source' --eval-command='dashboard source -style context 14' --eval-command='file program.elf' --eval-command='target remote :2331' --eval-command='monitor reset'`. This suits me better as I didn't need to add one more file. In my shel script I used `\` at the end of each argument to split my command over multiple lines and it looks great.